# Adding number and get wrong output

Tags: javascript

```
const [shipping, setShipping] = useState({
        overseas: '3'
    })

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setShipping({ overseas: e.target.value })  //can change to 8 or 3
    }
    const selection = shipping.overseas

console.log(selection)   // result from selection are correct

    const getTotal = () => {
        return products.reduce((currentValue, nextValue) => {
            return  (currentValue + selection + nextValue.count * nextValue.price);
        }, 0);
    };
```

currentValue is 0 , selection is either 3 or 8 , nextValue is 23
when getting the result instead of a total add on number it became 0323   instead of 23+3 which is 26

Comment: `const selection = parseInt(shipping.overseas)` shipping.overseas is a string so need to cast it to int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
const [shipping, setShipping] = useState({
        overseas: '3'
});

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setShipping({ overseas: e.target.value});  //can change to 8 or 3
};
const selection = parseInt(shipping.overseas);

console.log(selection);   // result from selection are correct

const getTotal = () => {
    return products.reduce((currentValue, nextValue) => {
        return  (currentValue + selection + nextValue.count * nextValue.price);
    }, 0);
};
```

The basic problem is that JS is recognizing "selection" as a string, instead of a numeric value.  So it's "concatenating", instead of "adding".

Answer (score 0):

probably `selection` is string, and it makes all the equation to string. so **0 + '3' + 23 = 0323**. use `Number(shipping.overseas)` or `+shipping.overseas` to make it real number

Answer (score 0):

you can do these to fix

```
const selection = parseInt(shipping.overseas);
```

or

```
const selection =+shipping.overseas
```